# how to convert byte array into a signed big integer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, biginteger

There are some excellent biginteger.js libraries out there. Currently I am using [jsbin.js by Tom Wu](https://code.google.com/p/cryptico/source/browse/trunk/jsbn.js?r=2) to exchange matching SRP proof-of-password hashes between a browse and java on the server.

My problem is that I cannot seem to easily convert a byte array representing a large signed integer into a Javascript BigInteger which matches the Java code below. This is required to be able to hash at the browser in a way which matches two `RFC 5054` compliant java cryto libraries (bounceycastle and nimbusds). The two java libraries which do `H(A,B)` hashing of the SRP protocol as:

```
byte[] output = digest.digest(); // sha256 digest gives byte array
return new BigInteger(1, output); // 1 indicates positive number
```

That does not work with the bsbin.js library as it does not have a constructor which takes a signed byte array. Javascript doesn't have signed bytes. Whats the easy way to do the same `H(A|B)` conversion to signed data in javascript in a way which works with the two published libraries which use the byte array constructor of `java.math.BigInteger`?

Something like the following would work to convert the signed byte array into a large decimal string:

```
var output = moduleSHA256.hashToBinaryArray(message); // sha256 digest gives byte array
var signedNumberString = someConversion(output); // ???
return new BigInteger(signedNumberString); // this value toString(16) must match Java code
```

I am also willing to try a different javascript BigInteger library which has all the math logic of the bsbin.js library but which has a signed byte array style constructor.

N.B. [RFC2945](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2945.txt) points out that converting a sequence of bytes into a big number is one key implementation issue worth specifying for interoperable SRP negotiation and specifies:

> An n-byte string S can be converted to an integer as follows:
>
> i = S[n-1] + 256 * S[n-2] + 256^2 * S[n-3] + ... + 256^(n-1) * S[0]

The problem as stated above is that the Java code uses the byte array constructor of BigInteger which is not platform portable rather than the documented conversion given in RFC2945.

(**Edit** Please note I have successfully edited the opensource  Java cryptography libraries in question to do `H(A|B)` hashing as trivial string concat and got everything all working fine exchanging SRP password proofs with a browser. Yet I don't want to use nor publish my own edited versions of java cryptography libraries. I want to write javascript which is compatible with original and unedited java SRP crypto logic).

(**Edit** Please note one 'fix' is the change the java to hex encode the byte array returned by the hash then use the constructor `new BigInteger(hexstring,16)` which is more platform portable. That would give an entirely different number to the number given from `new BigInteger(hashbytes)` but is repeatable in Javascript and works when I tried that. Once again I don't want to publish edited java crypo libraries so this is not a solution).

**Update** I actually got around this problem by using a new extension point in one of the java libraries to plug in a `hash -> hex string -> BigInteger` approach. The problem still stands for people wanted to make Javascript run like java which uses the byte array constructor of BigInteger.

Comment: Why do you need a JavaScript BigInteger "*to exchange matching hashes with the java server*"? What math logic does that require?

Comment: Have you looked at/tried [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)?  It has a number of common hash functions.  It is higher level, but why reinvent the wheel unless you need something different?

Comment: If you are only going to compare hex strings at the end, using a big integer intermediate seems like overkill. Simply convert each byte to two hex digits (i.e. make sure to pad with zero if required), then concatenate these.

Comment: @Bergi SRP cryptography protocol as per https://github.com/RuslanZavacky/srp-6a-demo which I am porting to java. I have already rewritten in Java and got it all working hashing strings in a way trivial to do identically at both the browser and the server. Yet I prefer to not to publish my own java crypto code; I want to hash the same way as a trust crypo library (bouncycastle.org or another i am looking at). Since I have it all working but wont publish it until I can drop in a trust java library   without changing the hashing I need to solve the problem as stated.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your byte array to a hex string:

```
// convert a byte (0-255) to a hex string with two characters 'XX'
function dec2hex(value) {
  return (i + 0x100).toString(16).substr(-2).toUpperCase();
}

var hexStr = byteArray.map(dec2hex).join('');
```

and then load this hex string into a bignumber library like [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js):

```
var num = new BigNumber(hexStr, 16);
```

Comment: That does not help me. The byte array and the hex representation of a number are not interchangeable; I cannot change how the java uses the byte array. It has its own meaning to how to interpret the signed bytes. I actually got confused about this myself and wasted a few hours before asking here. The java library relies upon the internal representation of BigInteger to turn a hash into a number. That is very fast but not easily portable between Java and Javascript. I updated the question to point out RFC5054 defines a portable conversion method. Yet I cannot modify the Java libraries.

Comment: Worked for me, I've simplified it: 

`BigInt('0x' + array.map(byte => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert no more than 64 bits (8 bytes) of TypedArray into a BigInt then I think the fastest way is a DataView over underlying array buffer:

```
let arr = new UInt8Array(8); // this is the input array
let bigint = new DataView(arr.buffer).getBigInt64(); // you can pass offset in the array and endianness here
```

You might extend that solution to convert arbitrary lengths of data into a single BigInt.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem i was looking for java Big Intege.toByteArray()  and converting this into back in javascript.

i used https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer
and used following code

`BigInteger(bn).toArray(256).value` worked for me.

Comment: [`BigInt` has been natively supported by all major browsers since about 2018.](https://caniuse.com/bigint) There is very little reason to take an additional dependency for this unless you need to support ancient user agents for some reason.